# Morse code in Arduino Mega 2560, using buttons and a buzzer

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I'm trying to make a simple morse code in Arduino, using a breadboard, one buzzer and two buttons. When button1 is pushed, the output of the buzzer should be a sound signal for 200ms. If the other button (button2) is pushed, the output of the buzzer should be a sound signal for 400ms.

Also when button1 is pushed the program should print "." to the screen. Similarly, print "-" for the longer output.

This is my code:

```
const int buttonPin1 = 10;
const int buttonPin2 = 8;
const int buzzPin = 13;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  noTone(buzzPin);

  if (buttonPin1 == true) {
    Serial.println('.');
    tone(buzzPin, 1000);
    delay(200);
  }
  else if (buttonPin2 == true) {
    Serial.println('-');
    tone(buzzPin, 1000);
    delay(400);
  }
}
```

Currently, it does not work, and I am not sure what's incorrect if it is my code or the circuit. I am not receiving any output, either from the buzzer or in Arduino.

I would appreciate if anyone could guide me onto the right tracks.

Thanks.

Comment: *Currently, it does not work,* -- Please be a little more detailed than just saying "it does not work".

Comment: *I am not sure what's incorrect if it is my code or the circuit.* Test them independently. Test the parts of the software independently too - building it in small steps. Then when any particular step is not working, it limits where you need to look for the problem. Suppose you build the whole code and there are *three* problems? That is much harder to solve, because solving a single one of the problems, won't show a result.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for the tip, I will definitely try to do so in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buttonPin1 == true` and `buttonPin2 == true` are compareing `true` with the pin number, not the status of pins.

You should use [`digitalRead()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalread/) function to check status of pins.

```
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  noTone(buzzPin);

  if (digitalRead(buttonPin1) == HIGH) { // check pin status instead of doing constant comparision
    Serial.println('.');
    tone(buzzPin, 1000);
    delay(200);
  }
  else if (digitalRead(buttonPin2) == HIGH) { // check pin status instead of doing constant comparision
    Serial.println('-');
    tone(buzzPin, 1000);
    delay(400);
  }
}
```